# C# equivalent of the VB.Net select case true

Tags: c#, vb.net, switch-statement

I'm trying to find a C# equivalent of the VB.Net `Select Case True`, which I found very useful in the past. In VB.Net, I could write (an arbitrary example where a property is of type object and either passed a Boolean value, or an instance of class Expression):

```
Select Case True
    Case value Is Nothing:
        Throw New Exception("Invalid value.")

    Case value.ToString() == "True":
        moValue = value

    Case value.ToString() == "False":
        moValue = value

    Case value.GetType().Name = "Expression":
        moValue.DataTypeCode = "BOOLEAN"
        moValue = value

    Case Else:
        Throw New Exception("Invalid value.")
End Select
```

I'm aware of the switch statement, obviously, but the case values cannot be expressions, as far as I can tell. Although C# practitioners may balk at the above, I found it very useful, because it lays out my test cases in a list with the precedence of order of analysis.

Is there a C# construct where I can have a bunch of test cases in a list like this and process the first one that evaluates to true, without having to nest a bunch of if...else's?

Comment: The idiomatic equivalent is an `if/else if/else if/.../else` expression. No need to nest them. You *can* use a switch statement with `when` clauses to do this, but please don't

Comment: c# can have [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)

Comment: Curious as to how you find "Select Case True" useful compared to writing If/Else sequence. The Select Case True doesn't appear to give you anything useful and if anything obfuscates the logic. Note that there is no need to nest, as @canton7 pointed out.

Comment: @gunr2171: The goal is to not purposely make it harder to understand.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I fully agree that using switches like this (in either language) makes it harder to understand, just pointing out that switch expressions exist, though probably are not a 100% translation.

Comment: @gunr2171: Understood. Now that C# designers have decided to make it an 'experimental' language, novice developers are racing to use the experimental features in places where they add neither clarity nor efficacy.

Comment: Regards which is easier to read, I think that is down to what you're used to. I find the if/else structure makes it harder to pick out the individual test bases and the Select Case statement easier, but that's just down to history and preference. Thanks all.

Comment: I've not come across ```when``` before. What's the main objection to it?

Comment: @MarkRoworth see [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/42IkgG), you could do the `value.GetType().Name`, known as a recursive pattern in the case, but that requires language version >= 8.0. On another note, canton7 answer is best in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you'd write this is an `if/else if/else` statement:

```
if (value == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid value");
}
else if (value.ToString() == "True" || value.ToString() == "False")
{
    moValue = value;
}
else if (value.GetType().Name == "Expression")
{
    moValue.DataTypeCode = "BOOLEAN";
    moValue = value;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid value");
}
```

You *can* do this with a [switch statement with `when` clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause), but please don't.

---

As an aside, that slightly verbose case:

```
else if (value.ToString() == "True" || value.ToString() == "False")
```

can also be written as the more concise pattern:

```
else if (value.ToString() is "True" or "False")
```

Comment: Thanks @canton7. I've been using curly brackets after the else until now, as otherwise it seems to me that the grammar is ambiguous. For instance, does the last else above relate to the first if, or the last one? Depends where you put the brackets. Could I ask what the issue with ```when``` is? I've not come across it before.

Comment: The sequence is that the `if` is evaluated first, then if that isn't matched, the `else if` is evaluated, then the `else if` after, etc, top-to-bottom. If execution reaches the `else` but none of the arms of the `if/else if` have been matched, execution enters the `else`. This behaviour is common across all languages which have this construct

Comment: It's exactly the same as the `Case / Case / Case Else` in your question -- the `else` works the same way that your `Case Else` works.